# For file reading, when to use filebuf

Tags: c++, file-io, iostream, filebuf

I'm going to be doing random-access reading from a read-only binary file.  The interface to ifstream seems simpler than filebuf; but is there any use-case where filebuf would give better performance?

More details:  I have a file of fixed-length (48-byte) records, and will be doing random-access reads in sequence -- read 1 record, process, read 1 record (from elsewhere), process, ....  (Traversing a tree.)  The file never changes.  Since the records are fixed-length, I may later use a "character-type" that is the 48-byte record, but I don't imagine that has any performance effect.

Comment: Order of a million in the file -- traversing the tree will require that order of 50 get read.  (Nearest neighbor search through a kb tree.)
And you might then think I should read the whole file into RAM, since the file is only ~50MB -- but there will actually be about 80 such files, so the memory usage of reading all of the files would be very large.

Comment: Oops -- a kd tree, not kb tree.  Typo.

Answer (score 0):

May be if you are on Linux may be using mmap would get around the whole problem of reading the file bit by bit.

Or boost memory mapped files?
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html